# How to display resource usage gadget on my Unity desctop?

Tags: unity, gnome, indicator, widgets

I am confused.

So, Unity is a set of tools, put on top of Gnome 2, and giving it a new look and feel? And Gnome 3 is something different.

All I manage to do is create quick-launch favourites, as well as desktop shortcuts. However, the great customazability of Gnome 2 Classic is gone to me.

How do I get something, similar to this (the two graphical indicators in the top bar)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity no longer uses the old applet system. Instead, there are **indicators**.

One such indicator is **indicator-multiload**, which shows CPU and memory usage. It is included in Ubuntu's repositories and can be installed using your package manager of choice.

On a general note: Unity is not based on Gnome 2, it just uses GTK2-based programs like Gnome 2 did.

Comment: Sorry about the off-topic, I am confused about the terminology. If Gnome is a "desktop environment" and Unity is a "user interface", what is the difference between the two (classes of things)?

Comment: A desktop environment usually comes with a set of matched applications to configure your system and execute basic tasks. While Ubuntu (with Unity) also has applications preinstalled, these are usually not considered part of Unity.

Comment: Works great. I added it to my Startup Apllications.